# Print array values in Go

Tags: arrays, go

I'm trying to define an array in struct in Go, devices array should have 3 items of type strings, but I can't find out how to print values of devices array

Below outputs "mismatched types string and [2]string". Any hints?

```
type Nodes struct {
Nodes []Node `json:"nodes"`
}

type Node struct {
devices       [2]string `json:"devices"`
}

var nodes Nodes
fmt.Println("Device: %+v" + nodes.Nodes[i].devices)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is because you're trying to concatenate a `string` and a `[2]string`:

```
"Device: %+v" + nodes.Nodes[i].devices
```

Specifically, `"Device: %+v"` is a string, and `nodes.Nodes[i].devices` is a `[2]string`.

But at higher level, this is the result of improperly using `fmt.Println`, made apparent by the use of a formatting verb `%+v`, which makes no sense in the context of `Println`. What you probably want is `fmt.Printf`:

```
fmt.Printf("Device: %+v\n", nodes.Nodes[0].devices)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use fmt.Printf instead of Println :

```
fmt.Printf("Device: %+v", nodes.Nodes[i].devices)
```

Or you can do something like this :

```
for _, node := range nodes.Nodes {
    for _, device := range node.devices {
        fmt.Println("Device : " + device)
    }
}
```

The output :

```
Device : Android
Device : iOS
```